# Need help in finding bug (which relates to char** copying) in C program

Tags: c

I tried different way of copying char** to char**, but everything seems to be unsuccessful. Here is my code:

```
void allocate(char ***words, unsigned long stringLength){
    *words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * stringLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        (*words)[i] = malloc(stringLength);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

char **charArray;
allocate(&charArray, strlen(argv[2]));

int i, j;

for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    argv++;
    j = 0;
    while((*argv)[j]){
        (*charArray)[j] = (*argv)[j];
        j++;
    }
    charArray++;
}

printf("%s\n", charArray[0]);
printf("%s\n", charArray[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Print statements do not print correct words from argument list, it seems like it prints some empty spaces.. I have no idea why it does not work. I am not sure if it is an issues with space allocation or pointer arithmetic. I hope you will help me to figure that out. Thank you

Comment: You seem to be confusing the string length with the number of strings.  Shoudn't `allocate()` take both the string length and the number of strings as parameters?

Comment: there are a bunch of problems with this code, but stackoverflow isn't a debugging service.

Comment: The `allocate` funtion is wrong. `malloc` allocates a number of bytes, however you are writing `malloc(stringLength)` to allocate a number of pointers.

Comment: @KeithNicholas ok, is it difficult to help? I am trying to figure out the right way of doing it for 2 days already.. I need some hint. There is nobody I can ask help from

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759140/copying-command-line-arguments-into-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void allocate(char ***words, int argc, char **argv){
    *words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        (*words)[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char **charArray;
    allocate(&charArray, argc-1, argv+1);

    int i,j;
    char **pp = charArray;
    for(i = 1;i < argc; i++){
        argv++;
        j = 0;
        while((*argv)[j]){
            (*pp)[j] = (*argv)[j];
            j++;
        }
        (*pp)[j] = '\0';
        pp++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", charArray[0]);
    printf("%s\n", charArray[1]);
    for(int i=0; i < argc-1; ++i)
        free(charArray[i]);
    free(charArray);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void makeCopyOfArgv(char ***words, int argc, char **argv){
    *words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        (*words)[i] = calloc(strlen(argv[i])+1, sizeof(char));
        for(int j = 0; argv[i][j] ; j++)//use strcpy
            (*words)[i][j] = argv[i][j];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char **charArray;
    makeCopyOfArgv(&charArray, argc-1, argv+1);

    printf("%s\n", charArray[0]);
    printf("%s\n", charArray[1]);
    for(int i=0; i < argc-1; ++i)
        free(charArray[i]);
    free(charArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you A LOT. You saved me.
Can you explain me
(*words)[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
Why don't you use here sizeof(char)?
Not sure how it works...

Comment: I also do not understand how second code works...
We have two double pointer chars **argv and **charArray. Why function makeCopyOfArgv accepts triple pointer for **charArray argument and same double pointer for **argv. Why they are not both the same triple pointers?

Comment: @PutinHuylo It can be omitted because `sizeof(char)` is determined to 1 by the standard.

Comment: @PutinHuylo `word` must be a triple pointer in order to write back to `charArray`.